# Wordpress/WooCommerce: woocommerce_thankyou not working with Stripe payments

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

In the latest update, it appears that Stripe payment processing is done by the user of separate WC/Stripe plugin. Since then, my `wp_enqueue_script()` stopping working on my confirmation page. It still works for Cash on Delivery payments.

Here is what I have for COD payments (this works):

`add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( 'MyApp', 'myapp_woocommerce_thankyou' ), 1000 );`

Here is what I have to track the Stripe payments (DOESN'T work):

`add_action( 'wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment', array( 'MyApp', 'myapp_woocommerce_thankyou_wc3_stripe' ), 1000, 2 );`

Then I have these functions. One for Stripe and one for all else:

```
public static function myapp_woocommerce_thankyou($order_id) {

    echo 'Test'; // Works on both payment methods

    $myapp_vars = array( 'num' => rand() ); // Dummy data

    // Load the JS
    wp_register_script( "scripts" , plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "/myapp.js" );
    wp_enqueue_script( "scripts" );
    wp_localize_script( "scripts" , "myapp_vars", $myapp_vars );


}

public static function myapp_woocommerce_thankyou_wc3_stripe( $stripe_response, $order ) {

    MyApp::myapp_woocommerce_thankyou( $order->get_id() );

}
```

I am able to echo out data in `myapp_woocommerce_thankyou()`, but the `wp_localize_script` part simply won't run when the customer pays via Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am using WooCommerce and they changed their API. Unfortunately WP/WC wasn't reporting back the errors by default. I had to go hunt them down like a lion in heat looking for a mate.